# runtime added application:openURL not fires

Tags: ios, facebook

For some reason I develop static library for facebook connection.

For proper process authorizated URL appDelegate should have
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation

method.
So when I code it in appDelegate.mm file all works well, method invokes and facebook session become authorized.
But I have to add this method to delegate in runtime, so I use follow code:

```
{
NSString* methodDescription;

methodDescription = @"B@:@@@@";
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

bool res = class_addMethod([app.delegate class],     @selector(application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:), (IMP)applicationIMP,     [methodDescription UTF8String]);
NSLog(@"Result of add method is %d", res);
}
```

//here is implementation of new method:

```
 bool applicationIMP(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSURL *url, NSString     *sourceApplication, id annotation)
 {
NSLog(@"Log from applicationIMP injected method");
return [[LibSocial sharedInstance] FacebookHandleOpenURL:url];
 }
```

this code successfully adds method (I see this method when calls class_copyMethodList):
2013-02-04 23:02:00.704 LibSocialTest[38167:19a03] Mathod[0] is application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

But Facebook SDK doesn't fire this method after authentication, and I got FBSessionState FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed.

Why this method didn't fired?

**Update:**
Even if I replace normally implemented method with custom implementation at runtime, all works well and Facebook SDK fires new method implementation. But if I didn't code normally this method, but add it at runtime, it isn't fires.

**Update2**
If I add method to appDelegate class before instantiating UIApplication (in main.m file), then injected method works (even there are no default implementation of method in appDelegate.mm file), but if I inject method after UIApplication was created (so instance of appDelegate class was created too), then injection of method doesn't affect on already instantiated instances of class.

Comment: Does the method fire when you implement it normally?

Comment: yes. Even if I replace normally implemented method with custom implementation at runtime, all works well and Facebook SDK fires new method implementation. But if I didn't code normally this method, but add it at runtime, it isn't fires.

Comment: I had this same problem. Am I understanding your update correctly, that if you're somehow able to call "class_addMethod" prior to "UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SZTAppDelegate class]));", then you are able to add the implementation at runtime and it is called?